# Why is .compare returning 1?

Tags: c++

I understand that for strings `y` and `x`, and `x.compare(y)` is equal to 0, then both strings are equal. When I input an equal string for `x` using `getline(cin,x)`, I'm getting 1 returned instead of 0. Why is this happening? Should I just account for `x.compare(y) == 1` meaning that they are equal?

I have tried making `k==0` in my if statement, but it's not returning 0. I feel like `getline()` is adding additional data to the string, causing `compare()` to return `1` instead of `0`.

Here's my code:

```
int main(void) {
    string x;
    string y = "Hello World";
    getline(cin,x);
    int k = x.compare(y);
    cout << k;
    if (k==0) {
        cout << "Hi";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _I feel like getline() is adding additional data to the string_ no, it doesn't. do you input exactly `Hello World`?

Comment: As @user3365922 mentioned, the problem is with what you entering by keyboard.
Simply check with ```x = "Hello World";```. 
BTW I don't know why some one voted down this question. But I hope he/she  removes his/her down-vote.

Comment: [Looks good to me.](https://ideone.com/9ytLM6)

Comment: The code works for me too (I ran it from a terminal on my computer). Whatever the problem is, it's not in the information you've given us so far. My best guess is that you entered "hello world" or "Hello world" instead of "Hello World", but you're the one in the best position to check that. Maybe you could have your code output both `x` and `y`, then show us the output?

Comment: The first thing to do when two values don't compare equal and you expect them to is to **look at the values**. Either add an output statement that shows what's in `x` and what's in `y` or run the code in a debugger so that you can inspect `x` and `y`.

Answer (score -1):

int string::compare (const string& str) const
Returns:

- 0 : if both strings are equal.
- A value < 0 : if *this is shorter than str or, first character that
  doesn't match is smaller than str.
- A value > 0 : if *this is longer than str or, first character that
  doesn't match is greater